# term.js placement always end of body

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I am new to javascript and have problems placing this element.

I can open terminals and write to them no problem. However everytime I create one it is just appended to my body at the very end.

according to this example:
https://gist.github.com/steinwaywhw/9920493

I could set a parent during the `open` method but I use this and it just still appends to the end of the body.

This is the method I use:

```
term.open($("#myterm").find("div")[0])
```

I might be overlooking really simple but I cannot seem to find it :/

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with term.js and jquery selectors, please test with getElementById like :

```
<div id="term"></div>

term.open(document.getElementById("term"));
```

it work for me.

Pascal

Comment: <div id="term"></div> and term.open($("#term")[0]); work also for me on last master